# How to get the distinct elements?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a class as under

```
class WarningClass
    {
        public string SqlEyeWarning { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }
```

It is populated as under

```
List<WarningClass> lstWarningClass1 = new List<WarningClass>();
lstWarningClass1.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD001: order mismatch or it should be ON." });
lstWarningClass1.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD001: order mismatch or it should be ON." });
lstWarningClass1.Add(new WarningClass { FileName = "c.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD009: Missing or order mismatch of Grant statement." });
```

As can be make out that there is a duplicate entry for the first and second record.

How to get unique entries.

**Final output**

```
FileName = "a.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD001: order mismatch or it should be ON." 
FileName = "c.sql", SqlEyeWarning = "SD009: Missing or order mismatch of Grant statement."
```

If I do `lstWarningClass1.Distinct()`, that does not work

Comment: Implement the `IEquatable<WarningClass>` interface, and the `District` method will probably work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IEnumerable.GroupBy` to group the objects in the list by the criteria that you care about.  Then, you can select the first element of each group.

You can group by `FileName` like so:

`lstWarningClass1.GroupBy(w => w.FileName).Select(g => g.First())`

or by `FileName` and `SqlEyeWarning` like so:

`lstWarningClass1.GroupBy(w => new {w.FileName, w.SqlEyeWarning}).Select(g => g.First())`

Comment: Mind explaining what you're doing a bit?  Your answer will be more helpful that way.

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem that he is grouping my `FileName` only, but all properties.

Comment: @YoryeNathan That may be true, but the example he gave was ambiguous.  I'll amend my answer to include grouping by multiple properties.

Answer (score 3):

Linq's Distinct() has the following in its description:

The default equality comparer, Default, is used to compare values of the types that implement the **IEquatable generic interface. To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.**

Do the bolded part and Distinct() will work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a customize `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<WarningClass>
{
    public bool Equals(WarningClass x, WarningClass y)
    {
        return x.SqlEyeWarning.Equals(y.SqlEyeWarning)
               && x.FileName.Equals(y.FileName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(WarningClass obj)
    {
        return obj.FileName.GetHashCode() 
            ^ obj.SqlEyeWarning.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then call overloaded `Distinct` method with your customize comparer:

```
var result = lstWarningClass1.Distinct(new CustomComparer());
```